# Utilizing parameter objects with <T> in Java

Tags: java, function, generics, parameters

So I have been tinkering around with Java, and was wondering the difference in the following:

```
public void insert(Node<T> node) {
    //insertion code
}

vs 

public TreeNode<T> insert(Node node) {
   //insertion code
}
```

Assuming Node is a class declared:

```
public class Node<T> {
   //member variables
   //member functions 
}
```

Both methods compile and achieve the same goal. However, I was wondering if the first method eg. insert(Node`<T>` node) is simply more verbose and explicit than insert(Node node).

Comment: The first empowers the compiler to check that you're only doing operations that are appropriate to a `Node<T>`.  The second basically switches off any kind of type checking on types that are used generically, so leaves you open to all kinds of problems.  Don't do it!

Comment: It honestly depends on what your `insert` function wants to do with the node. For instance, if node has some variable of type `T`, then `insert<T>` would be able to safely access that value's properties and methods, or alternatively, if as @DawoodibnKareem describes, you only want `insert` to accept nodes of type `T`.